# TestNG run method as last

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

is there a way how to run specific test method as **last one** in TestNG? I do not want to use `dependsOn` if I do not need to do so.

Thank you

Comment: is it teardown code?

Comment: No, it is a test method, but in case it fail, it could affect other methods. But I solved that adding `dependsOn` on all methods previous methods together.

Comment: Try adding priority to the  method you want to run last..do not add priorities to any other methods.  The one with priority added would run last, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, sounds great. Sorry, I still cannot vote your comment :(

Comment: I will put it as an answer, if it has helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add priority to the method you want to run last..do not add priorities to any other methods. The one with priority added would run last.